# Assign specific role (Authentication) to a Firebase Console user

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I have a Firebase app, and I want to know if it's possible to restrict a Firebase Console user to access only to the "Authorizations" tab. (to CRUD users). The access must be by the Firebase (regular) Web Console

[image: Firebase console screenshot]

Especially, I don't want the user to see the database data via the web console. Is that possible? I've managed to give him access to the entire project, and he can do anything I can do (is an Admin).

I haven't found nothing about this in the docs / searching.

Comment: No, you can't as of now. But you can always create a separate dashboard for the other admin that routes all the queries via your admin server. Creating a separate dashboard is also helpful/ scalable as you can implement custom access restrictions for different future admins

Comment: @gonephishing that was my thoughts, thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Collaborators on a project currently have access to the entire Firebase Console. You can limit to having read-only access, but you currently can't limit what panels they have access to.

We've heard the request before and know this would expand the usefulness of the Firebase Console. I recommend that your [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), to add your vote.

Comment: I understand this is not the most appropriate place to mention this, but since we are talking about it. Amazon has a lot of features like this, something that makes Firebase more attractive to get started is the simplicity, everything is user-friendly. If you can add roles keeping Firebase as nice as it is today, I will be super glad :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks Frank! Feature request sent ;)