# Setting IAM roles for Firebase access

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, google-cloud-console

I have a Firebase account linked to a Google Cloud account. I want to add a collaborator to Firebase, but not allow them to have access to our entire GCP account.

There is no role or ability to create a custom role to grant access to Firebase. Is there a way to do this without granting broad GCP access?

Comment: Create a project and give that project only access to Firebase in the IAM. Then add the user to the project.

Comment: What do you want the users to be able to access? And what don't you want them to be able to access? If you want them to be able to see certain Firebase products in the console but not others, that is currently not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585948/assign-specific-role-authentication-to-a-firebase-console-user/45593018#45593018

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'd like the user to be able to access everything in Firebase, but nothing in Compute Engine. (actually, it's really only a few instances - but the user that needs to access Firebase doesn't have a need to mess with Compute Engine)