# Firebase console access configuration

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I see I can configure user access to my Firebase console and apps via Google IAM. However the permissions defined there are tailored toward Google Cloud rather than Firebase.

What I'd like to do is configure user accounts so "Larry" in Marketing can access firebase Analytics but not DB or Functions. "Bob" in Product can access remote config but not authentication...etc.

Instead it seems to me all I can do is give users read/write/own permissions, and nothing else.

Is this possible, if not, is it on the road map?

Comment: That is currently not possible: collaborators have access to all products in the Firebase console. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585948/assign-specific-role-authentication-to-a-firebase-console-user