# Firebase console IAM role for Firebase Analytics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-analytics, firebase-console, google-cloud-iam

How do we set up a role for Firebase console user that allows the user to create funnels and audiences (Project Editor role) for analytics data, while restricting access to BigQuery and Cloud Storage resources?

Comment: This currently isn't possible: someone who has access to the Firebase console of your project has access to all products within there. While you can limit them to read-only permission, you can't limit them to certain products. Work is under way to change this situation, but as usual: no timelines or estimates. Note that BigQuery access is managed from the Cloud console, which (afaik) already supports such role based access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign specific role (Authentication) to a Firebase Console user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585948/assign-specific-role-authentication-to-a-firebase-console-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase [now provides two predifined roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-category#analytics_roles) related to Google Analytics reports, `roles/firebase.analyticsAdmin` and `roles/firebase.analyticsViewer`. This allows basic access control, but not any sort of per-report or restricted editor permissions.

Note that BigQuery can be managed by [IAM permissions through Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).